# Python 2.7 base64.b64decode why does it return a string and not a byte array?

Tags: python

I am using Python 2.7 to decode base64 data and I don't understand why base64.b64decode returns a string?  How do I get to the binary data that is decoded?  I would think base64.b64decode would return a byte array.  Here is the link to python docs for base64:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html

Thanks for the help!

Comment: There is no such thing as a `byte` type in Python 2. It was introduced in Python 3. You just have the `str` and `unicode` types in Python 2.

Answer (score 4):

In 2.x a **bytestring** *is* the binary data, represented in a mostly-printable form. And it doesn't require additional modules for support.

Answer (score 4):

The *bytearray* type is used when we want **mutable** strings or arrays of bytes.

The *b64decode()* function uses a *str* type which is for **immutable** strings or arrays of bytes in Python 2.7.

Besides not needing mutability, the other reason that *b64decode()* didn't consider returning a bytearray is that *b64decode()* is much older than bytearrays -- when the only tool in your toolbox is a str, all problems start to look like *str* problems ;-)

Comment: I just started using this module so my lack of experience might explain why this isn't a good question.  So here it goes if I take some binary data and encode it to base64 then when I decode it I would think it should be to a byte array.  I ran into a problem with some Python code I was working on when I tried to process the data as a string I received several exceptions.  So after I decode the data the very next thing I do is turn the result into a byte array.  Why would anybody want a string?  If that was the case the data wouldn't need to be base64 encoded in the first place.